# Wordpress, filter messages on main page

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I hide posts from some category with some ID from main page of my site? I need solution like filter:

```
function exclude_post($query) {
    if ($query->is_home) {
        ...
    }

    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_post');
```

Can somebody provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$query->set( $query_var, $value );` where $query_var is the variable you want to add/update in query. So put this inside your condition:

```
// 1st parameter is the query variable the 2nd is its value, in this case an array of category IDs
$query->set( 'category__not_in', array( 2, 6 ) );
```

Remember is good practice put in condition a check to `$query->is_main_query()`. `pre_get_posts` is an action hook so you have to change `add_filter` to `add_action`.
An action hook doesn't return a value, a filter does.

**Example**

```
function exclude_post( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
      $query->set( 'category__not_in', array( 2, 6 ) );
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_post');
```

**UPDATE**

According to the new details emerging by the question,in order to exclude some posts in feeds stream, but not in category archive, the conditional check might look like:

```
if( $query->is_feed() && !$query->is_archive() )
```

OR

```
if( $query->is_feed() && !$query->is_category() )
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I need your help again, I modified my function as recommended, now I need remove the same posts from RSS feed, i add condition `if ($query->is_home || $query->is_feed)` at home page is ok, but not in feed, I see all posts in feed

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko,try only `is_feed()` without other parameter and `$query->*`, and see what's going on feeds

Comment: When I use only `is_feed` then I see unneeded posts on main page and in RSS, I mean doesn't work (

Comment: Sorry, all works, Opera shoved me cashed RSS feed (not actual), thanks for the help!

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko, I came across with same conclusion just now! After several tests : ) it's ok

Comment: Sorry, but maybe you know how to separate main feed from other feeds? For example I don't want to show posts from some category in main feed, but I need them in feed of this category

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko, i think you should nest is_feed within is_home if statement, but i'm not sure.. give it a try. please let me know : )

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko, i may have the solution. I'm going to update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have answered on that question, I see that you guru in WP, can we communicate in social networks or via e-mail, you can find my contacts on my site zarezenko[dot]com. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the following way to exclude the a category from post query

```
 <?php 
 if ( is_home() ) 
 {
 query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-3');
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple exclude in the query parameters :-

```
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&show_count=1&exclude=10'); ?>
```

Its only sample , how to you exclude.

Hop it work..

Comment: Excuse me, but how wp_list_categories(); function can hide or show some posts? This function displays a list of categories as links and it's not used to get | retrieve posts

Comment: i am saying its a sample, you can use exclude in get post Query.. friend