# Wordpress hide category posts from main feed but show in category feed

Tags: php, wordpress

I am use this code for hide category posts from main feed:

```
function exclude_posts($query) {
    if ($query->is_feed()) {
        $query->set('category__not_in', array(17));
    }

    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_posts');
```

all works for main feed, but for other feeds too :( . And when I look at this category feed I don't see any posts. How can I hide category posts from main feed but not from category feed.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this one might work:
`if( $query->is_feed() && !$query->is_archive() )` or `if( $query->is_feed() && !$query->is_category() )`

Comment: Yes, second is solution, thanks!

Comment: for reference, i'll update the other answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530380/wordpress-filter-messages-on-main-page/18530770?noredirect=1#comment27336221_18530770

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code from:

```
if ($query->is_feed())
```

To:

```
if(is_feed() && !is_category() )
```